# Clicking the enter key/return key should trigger the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the items using the submit button click event. Right now I am trying to implement it so that when you enter the number to the input and hit enter, it should trigger the submit button and add the item to the table. I used the `keypress` event and it is not working. Here is [my sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/M8MHc/17/).

I think I am doing something wrong. My code below.

```js
// json data object
var data = JSON.parse('{ "122233334444": ["Book","Three Musketters","DE7598490587","7584092043857", "03/18/13 11:17:51 AM","03/18/13 11:17:51 AM", "1" ], "122223355552":["eBook","Fall Colors","XYZ29494949","7584092043857", "03/18/13 11:17:51 AM","03/18/13 11:17:51 AM", "2" ], "122223355533":["eBook","Snowfall","XYZ29494949","7584092043857", "03/18/13 11:17:51 AM","03/18/13 11:17:51 AM", "3" ] }');
$("#submitid").keypress(function() {
  $('#resend').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#receipt').prop('disabled', false);
  var rowId = $("#number").val();
  $("#number").val("");
  var rowData = data[rowId];
  if (rowData) {
    var tr = $("<tr><td><input id='item-id' type='checkbox' checked/></td></tr>").attr("id", "datatable-row-" + rowId);
    for (var col = 0; col < rowData.length; col++)
      tr.append($("<td></td>").text(rowData[col]));
    $("#datatable").prepend(tr);
    $("#datatable").show();
  } else {
    alert("Row doesn't exist in json object: " + rowId);
  }
});
$('#receipt').click(function() {
  $('.column-id').removeAttr('checked');
  $('#resend').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#receipt').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" type="text" />
<button id="submitid">Submit</button>

<table id="datatable">
  <colgroup>
    <col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-all column-id" id="item-id" title="Select All">
      </th>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" title="">Format</a></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" title="">Title</a></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" title="">Number</a></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" title="">Code</a></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" title="">Checkout Date</a></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" title="">Due Date</a></span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
        <div>
          <span><a href="#" title="">ItemId</a></span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="item-id" class="column-id" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Book</td>
      <td>Three Musketters</td>
      <td>DE7598490587</td>
      <td>7584092043857</td>
      <td>03/18/13 11:17:51 AM</td>
      <td>03/18/13 11:17:51 AM</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="resend" disabled>Resend</button>
<button id="receipt" disabled>Receipt</button>
```

Any suggestions?

krish

Comment: You are doing something wrong, you are not posting any code. Don't expect people to just follow your link.

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle `keydown` or `keypress` on the input not on the submit button:

```
$('#number').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Enter was pressed
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't it `keyCode === 13`?

Comment: @canon Yes I typed 2 instead of 1. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the things you should know
1) You need to know to *keycode of enter key* (which is **13**)

2) Since you tagged jQuery, learn [**event.which**](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), this property indicates the specific key or button that was pressed.

3) [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
$("#number").on('keypress', function (e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {  // check keycode condition       
   $('#submitid').trigger('click');
  }
  else {
  //Todos
  }
  e.preventDefault(); //Toprevent bounce
});
```

Comment: @krishyalla you doing wrong.  onkeypressing `textbox` triggers click event of `#submitid`.  But I dont see any 'click' event for submit button